# LG P880 Screen stays awake whilst charging

Tags: charging, screen, standby

I have a phone that when I plug it in it turns the screen on and the doesn't go to sleep until I press the power off button.  Is there a way to make the screen go to sleep automatically like when you just leave it normally and it goes to sleep after 30 seconds?

I have googled and tried most things i have found like checking the developer options to make sure the stay awake when charging box is unchecked and using the original power cable but nothing seems to work and as my personal phone automatically turned off I have got used to just plugging it in and leaving it to charge.

The problem with this new one is that when the screen is on whilst charging, it is so crap that the battery actually goes down rather than charging.  I hate the phone but can't get rid as it's a work phone